# Why am i getting the followng error when I called getline() in my C code?

Tags: gcc, getline

I am getting the following error

```
rudimentary_calc.c: In function ‘main’:
rudimentary_calc.c:9:6: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
   9 |  int getline(char line[], int max) ;
     |      ^~~~~~~
In file included from rudimentary_calc.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:616:18: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
 616 | extern __ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
     |                  ^~~~~~~
```

when I ran the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxline 100

int main()
{
    double sum, atof(char[]);
    char line[maxline];
    int getline(char line[], int max) ;

    sum = 0;

    while (getline(line, maxline) > 0)
        printf("\t %g \n", sum += atof(line));
    return 0;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am very new to C, so I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: You supply your own declaration for `getline` and other functions you didn't write yourself. That's what you are doing wrong. You should never do that. Instead, look in the documentation to figure out which header files you need to `#include` to use the functions.

Comment: Actually, this program is taken from the book "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie. I am following this book to learn C.

Comment: It is a good book, but it is old, and programming and the C language itself have changed since. What was good for K&R is not good today.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should not have to declare "built-in" functions as long as you #include the appropriate header files (in this case `stdio.h`).  The compiler is complaining that your declaration is not exactly the same as the one in `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 1):

The venerable K&R book defines a function named `getline`. The GNU C library also defines a non-standard function named `getline`. It is not compatible with the function defined in K&R. It is declared in the standard `<stdio.h>` header. So there is a name conflict (something that every C programmer has do deal with).

You can instruct GCC to ignore non-standard names found in standard headers. You need to supply a compilation flag such as `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` or any other `std=c<year>` flag that yout compiler supports.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h59a5qG5x)

Always use one of these flags, plus at least `-Wall`, to compile any C code, including code from K&R. You may encounter some compiler warnings or even errors. This is good. Thy will tell you that there are some code constructs that were good in the days of K&R, but are considered problematic now. You want to know about those. The book is rather old and the best practices and the C language itself have evolved since.